# Selenide driver implemention: TS2345 Argument of type 'WebDriver' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebDriver | (() => WebDriver)'

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, selenide

Im using selenidejs with typescript.
I first init a WebDriver with selenium, and then I implement it to the selenide Browser,
as seen in this link - docs to selenidejs:
https://github.com/KnowledgeExpert/selenidejs

When I try to do it like in the link, it shows the error in the title.
I need to implement the Browser like this, since i want to add arguments (chromeoptions) to the driver.

world.ts:

```
import { Builder, Capabilities } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { Browser } from 'selenidejs';

async init() {

    const webdriver = new Builder().withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome()).build();
    const browser = Browser.configuredWith()
        .driver(await webdriver) // the error happens here
        .baseUrl('https://google.com')
        .timeout(4000)
        .build();
}
```

many thanks for helping